# In fail, stop immediately job in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jobs

I have 6-7 methods in spring batch step which have catch blocks to catch errors. Then they come to that method:

```
private void failAndExit(Exception e) {
    sendEmail(e.getMessage());
    logger.info("Terminating CreditLifePoliciesJob job...");
    stepExecution.setExitStatus
            (new ExitStatus("FAILED",
                    e.getMessage()));

    if(!stepExecution.isTerminateOnly()) {
        stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();
    }
}
```

But after this method is completed, they go back to catch block and continues. How can I stop job? Should I use

```
System.exit
```

I dont want to return **status : failed** because i have 6-7 different methods, and nested method calls. It will be hard to do this.

It is a single tasklet and single step.

I assign this in step beginning:

```
  stepExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution();
```

Configuration:

```
SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob(JOB_NAME);
job.setSteps(Collections.singletonList(j(tasklet, batchJobRepository)));
job.setJobRepository(batchJobRepository);
return job;
```

and for step:

```
    public Step jobStep(CreditLifePolicyJobTasklet tasklet, JobRepository batchJobRepository) {
        TaskletStep step = new TaskletStep(JOB_STEP_NAME);
        step.setTasklet(tasklet);
        step.setJobRepository(batchJobRepository);
        transactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        step.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return step;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to terminate the sequential execution and close the job? If so move the logic to a sequence of TaskletStep and have a listener configured to listen to the step execution

Comment: @VigneshTI yes i want to exit after stopping job, without returning  to invoker. Do i have to return?

Comment: Don't use System.exit, you should let the job finish gracefully. `stepExecution.setTerminateOnly()` is used to signal that you want to terminate the step and its surrounding job. If you set it at some point, the surrounding job should be stopped. So I don't see (from what you shared) why this does not happen in your case.  `I dont want to return status : failed` Well, on one hand you set the status to FAILED in the `failAndExit ` method, and on the other hand you do not want to return status FAILED. What do you want then?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine i mean, there is no place to return status failed. I just want to throw different exceptions up on to errors and to log them and abort job. After throwing exception, the job should not go on but it continues. so i ıse `tepExecution.setTerminateOnly()` and `stepExecution.getJobExecution().stop()` and then throwing exception. Now it is working. I am doing those from a method. so each error catch, calls that method. Is it good practice?

Comment: No, calling `stop` on the job execution is not recommended as this method is deprecated for removal, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1605. `there is no place to return status failed`: you don't need to return an exit status, you set the one you want on the step execution and Spring Batch will stop the surrounding job accordingly.